# How to let spacing between buttons take up all available screen space in Flutter/Dart?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

Right now my screen looks like this:

[image]

This is the part of my code:

```dart
class MyStatelessWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyStatelessWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: Column(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: <Widget>[
          const SizedBox(height: 30),
          ClipRRect(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4),
            child: Stack(
              children: <Widget>[
                Positioned.fill(
                  child: Container(
                    decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                      gradient: LinearGradient(
                        colors: <Color>[
                          Color(0xFF0D47A1),
                          Color(0xFF1976D2),
                          Color(0xFF42A5F5),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                TextButton(
                  style: TextButton.styleFrom(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                    primary: Colors.white,
                    textStyle: const TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
                  ),
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.push(
                      context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const NewGameRoute()),
                    );
                  },
                  child: const Text('New Game'),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          const SizedBox(height: 30),
          ClipRRect(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4),
            child: Stack(
              children: <Widget>[
                Positioned.fill(
                  child: Container(
                    decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                      gradient: LinearGradient(
                        colors: <Color>[
                          Color(0xFF0D47A1),
                          Color(0xFF1976D2),
                          Color(0xFF42A5F5),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                TextButton(
                  style: TextButton.styleFrom(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                    primary: Colors.white,
                    textStyle: const TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
                  ),
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.push(
                      context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const NewGameRoute()),
                    );
                  },
                  child: const Text('Continue Game'),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          const SizedBox(height: 300), //300 as example
          ClipRRect(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4),
            child: Stack(
              children: <Widget>[
                Positioned.fill(
                  child: Container(
                    decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                      gradient: LinearGradient(
                        colors: <Color>[
                          Color(0xFF0D47A1),
                          Color(0xFF1976D2),
                          Color(0xFF42A5F5),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                TextButton(
                  style: TextButton.styleFrom(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                    primary: Colors.white,
                    textStyle: const TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
                  ),
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.push(
                      context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const NewGameRoute()),
                    );
                  },
                  child: const Text('Button 3'),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          const SizedBox(height: 30),
          ClipRRect(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4),
            child: Stack(
              children: <Widget>[
                Positioned.fill(
                  child: Container(
                    decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                      gradient: LinearGradient(
                        colors: <Color>[
                          Color(0xFF0D47A1),
                          Color(0xFF1976D2),
                          Color(0xFF42A5F5),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                TextButton(
                  style: TextButton.styleFrom(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                    primary: Colors.white,
                    textStyle: const TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
                  ),
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.push(
                      context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const NewGameRoute()),
                    );
                  },
                  child: const Text('Button 4'),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The large distance between the buttons is achieved due to:

```dart
const SizeBox(height: 300), //300 as example
```

But I want it to be relative. In other words, the distance between the two groups of these buttons should be the maximum, that is, occupy all the free space between them.

How to do it?

**Edi11**. Now it looks like this using Prabhakaran's code. It's cool. But how to make this distance as large as possible?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your button widget with Stack is unnecessary. And You can wrap the button with another column and use mainAxisAlignment of parent property like this. I created a button widget for you. So your code will look clean and minimalized.

```
class MyStatelessWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyStatelessWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: Column(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
        children: <Widget>[
          Column(
            children: [
              GradientButton(label: 'New Game', onTap: () {print('New Game');}),
              GradientButton(label: 'Continue Game', onTap: () {print('Continue Game');}),
            ],
          ),
          Column(
            children: [
              GradientButton(label: 'Button 1', onTap: () {print('Button 1');}),
              GradientButton(label: 'Button 2', onTap: () {print('Button 2');}),
            ],
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class GradientButton extends StatelessWidget {
  const GradientButton({Key? key, required this.label, required this.onTap}) : super(key: key);
  final String label;
  final Function onTap;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 15),
      child: GestureDetector(
        onTap: () => onTap(),
        child: Container(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20, vertical: 8),
          decoration: const BoxDecoration(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(4)),
            gradient: LinearGradient(
              colors: <Color>[
                Color(0xFF0D47A1),
                Color(0xFF1976D2),
                Color(0xFF42A5F5),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          child: Text(label, style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 20, color: Colors.white, fontWeight: FontWeight.normal, decoration: TextDecoration.none),),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, you are definitely right. Your code is much cleaner and clearer. But how to make this distance as large as possible? I made an explanation in Edit1.

Comment: change to MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween

Answer (score 1):

Instead of a sizedBox use `Spacer()`

Also set a bound to the patent container like

```
Container(
height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
width : MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
Column(
  children : [
     //First set of buttons here
     Spacer(),
    //Second set of buttons here
   ]
)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
const SizeBox(height: 300),
```

with

```
const Spacer(),
```

and remove

```
mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
```